# JUnit parametrized test with parametrized Spring ApplicationContext configuration

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-test, junit-jupiter, parametrized-testing

SpringBoot 2.2.11, JUnit 5.
My app has several environments. I have a test that tests some conditions in those environments rather than the application itself.

Therefore I want to reuse the same test method, but run it against different environments, as per environment variables / system properties.

So far, it is hard-coded:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = ["app.env=test"])
class EnvTest {
    @Test fun test01() {...}
}
```

And I want to use something like `@ParameterizedTest`.

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = ["app.env=test"])
class EnvTest {
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {"TEST", "PROD"})
    fun configCheck(env: String) {
        // Made-up for illustration
        spring.context.properties.put("app.env", env)
    }
}
```

Except, these parameters come too late, when the context is already created, and can't be taken into account by the test context manager. I want the parameters to be applied to the context creation.

All I could find so far [to parametrize the context at runtime](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) enables me to parametrize the beans - i.e. it's rather for app config rather than test config, like, `@ContextConfiguration`, or `@ConfigurationProperties`. Of course, I could also use profiles, and run a few times. But I prefer one run.

It seems to me that it's not possible, because what I want is at method level, but context creation can only be controlled at class level. So I can put the test to a base class, have several subclasses, and choose to run these based on the runtime parameters. But that's not as ellegant as `@ParametrizedTest` :)

**Is this possible with SpringBoot 2.2.x?**
Maybe `@ProfileValueSource` could be used somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible to parameterize a JUnit Jupiter test (method or class) with Spring bean definition profiles.

Related issues:

1. Spring: [Introduce support for executing a test class with different sets of profiles](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20849)
2. Spring: [Support @ContextConfiguration at method level](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/16647)
3. Spring: [Support @ActiveProfiles at method level](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/13977)
4. JUnit Jupiter: [Introduce extension API for container templates](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/871)

Ideally, JUnit Jupiter will introduce support for container templates at which point Spring Framework will be able to build on top of that support in order to allow an `ApplicationContext` to be created with various active profiles for parameterized invocations of the test class.

In the interim, the easiest way to achieve your goal is probably to define a base test class with common Spring configuration and common test methods and then introduce a subclass per combination of active profiles you wish to test. Annotating the base test class with `@DirtiesContext` would likely be beneficial since the contexts created for each subclass will likely not be used multiple times.

Comment: Wow I did not expect such specific answer, so I looked at your profile and... Thanks, my Zurich neighbour :)